# Illustrating global scope

Tags: javascript

I'm reading *You Don't Know JS - Scope and Closures* book.

It says, you shouldn't pollute the global scope. **foo** and **a** are polluting the global scope. for example:

```
var a = 2;
function foo() {
    var a = 3;
    console.log( a ); // 3
}
foo(); 
console.log( a ); //2
```

for this example I came up with a picture(**part of learning**).

[image]

for fixing this(polluting), he says wrap the code inside a anonymous function.

but, I have problem illustrating this. can you help me with this. it's important to illustrate it.

Comment: you have already a picture for an anonymous function, it's the red line. global object/variables are outside of the red egg.

Comment: Add a circle around everything but the red one, and call it "anonymous".

Comment: @NinaScholz I disagree, the global variables live inside the global scope, which is the red egg.

Comment: @procrastinator, when you look at the [venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram), there is a space outside of the circle. this is the global space. there is no space outside of global to address in  javascript.

Comment: @NinaScholz What would you put inside the purple egg then ?

Comment: A chicken ?  ........

Comment: the a? inside of `foo`.

Comment: If I follow your logic, the "a" should be outside of "foo" :-|

Comment: @NinaScholz Anyway, it's more a Meysam diagram than a Venn diagram :-P Each egg stands for a scope, and the variables outside of an egg are not part of the scope. Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems obvious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps. This is your example that additionally has an anonymous function.

```js
var a = 2;
console.log("global (start):", a); //2

(function() {
  var a = 42;
  console.log("inside anonimous function (start):", a); //42
  
  function foo() {
    var a = 3;
    console.log("inside foo():", a); //3
  }

  foo();
  console.log("inside anonimous function (end):", a); //42
})()

console.log("global (end):", a); //2
```

The image isn't the greatest but I hope it shows how the scopes are nested.

[image: illustration of scopes]

So, you can see that each of the scopes has it's own variable called `a` and does not touch the rest. This is because each uses `var a` to declare it. If the `var` part is omitted, then variable from the outer scope would be used

```js
var foo = 1;
console.log("global (start)", foo);

function bar() {
  console.log("inside bar(), before modification:", foo);
  foo = 7;
  console.log("inside bar(), after modification:", foo);
}

bar();
console.log("global (end)", foo);
```

[image]

Comment: I am fully aware of how bad the diagrams are but I suck at art. Any sort of art.

Comment: thank you for your time, another question, **a** is part of global scope and of course, **window**. where are those stored in window object? when you say, console.log(window), you can drill down to many details, right? which node contains my anonymous function and variables?

Comment: @Meysam first of all, yes - if `var a` is declared in the global scope then it will be part of the `window` object. As for your second question - an anonymous function will _not_ be assigned to `window`. That is part of their usefulness - you will not be able to get to the anonymous function, unless you assign a reference yourself, for example `var anon = (function(){ /* code */})()` but in that case the function has to have a return value. At this point, you are getting close to [the Module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).

Comment: Consider I did that, `var anon = (function(){ /* code */})()` which node of window object will contain it?

Comment: @Meysam assuming that is done in the global scope, it's going to be `window.anon`. However, again, the function needs to return something and _that_ will be the value of `anon`. For example `anon = (function() { var a = 1, b = 2; return b; })()` then the value of `anon` will be `2`. If you do `return { hello: "world", b: b }` then you will have that object assigned to the variable. You will not be able to access `a`. This is the reason anonymous functions are used to encapsulate variables - they are completely insulated.

Answer (score 0):

As @procrastinator suggested, encircle the red 'a' and foo and call it anonymous

Answer (score 0):

you can make it an IIFE

```js
(function foo() {
    var a = 3;
    console.log( a ); // 3
})();

 console.log( a )
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the question is about the diagram.